# How wide is the support for email alternateviews?

Tags: .net, email

So the standard email api in .net supports the use of "alternate views"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx

> Use the AlternateViews property to specify copies of an e-mail message in different formats. For example, if you send a message in HTML, you might also want to provide a plain text version in case some of the recipients use e-mail readers that cannot display HTML content.
>
> To add an alternate view to a MailMessage object, create an Attachment for the view, and then add it to the collection returned by AlternateViews. Use the Body property to specify the text version and use the AlternateViews collection to specify views with other MIME types. Use the MediaTypeNames class members to specify the MIME type for the alternate view.

How wide is the support for this approach? I am asking because I am curious if it is worth going to the effort of defining both text and html email bodies.

Comment: The sight-impaired with screen scrapers would probably use the straight text version. Support it if you can.

Answer (score 4):

I always use it to combine both html and text emails (such as newsletters). It's not that hard to implement, so I would just add the support:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();

// TODO: Set up normal message such as recipient, reply address, etc

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plainBody))
{
    var plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plainBody, null, "text/plain");
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(htmlBody))
{
    var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/html");
    if (linkedResources != null)
    {
        foreach (var linkedResource in linkedResources)
        {
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedResource);
        }
    }

    mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
}

return mail;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where a mail client will prefer a text alternative of an email over an HTML alternative of an email message. The Mail apps in both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 for instance will display the text alternative if available rather than the HTML version.

I made the mistake of putting the string "HTML only" as the text alternative in some emails along with the HTML message. All those clients were able to see was "HTML only". Removing the text alternative solved that problem.